# How to make MySQL run more efficiently?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

This query returns a suggestion list (hint) from a reliably small table, several thousand rows currently. But it returns the hint far too slowly to be very useful. Most of the other questions suggest polling the DB for where the slowdown is. I really don't have access at the level necessary to do that. It currently looks like below, maybe someone can help me see a technique I don't know. I would really like to speed up the following query.

```
$stmt = $db_found->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT callsign, Fname, ID, grid, 
                                tactical, latitude, longitude, email, Lname
        FROM NetLog 
        WHERE recordID IN (SELECT max(recordID) 
        FROM NetLog 
        WHERE callsign LIKE  ?
        AND callsign NOT IN ('W0KCN','WA0QFJ','T0EST','K0ERC','NR0AD')
        GROUP BY callsign)");
```

So that it pulls up the most current version of the recordID. recordID is the auto-increment variable in this table. If I remove the first FROM and WHERE then the query executes much faster. Like here;

```
$stmt = $db_found->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT callsign,  Fname, ID, grid, tactical, latitude, 
                                            longitude, email, Lname, recordID
        FROM NetLog 
        WHERE callsign LIKE ? 
        AND callsign NOT IN ('W0KCN','WA0QFJ','T0EST','K0ERC','NR0AD')
        GROUP BY callsign");
```

The problem is there is no guarantee that this is the most current record.

How can I speed up the return, and still be sure I'm getting the most current recordID for this callsign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to verifying the actual operation with an execution plan you can try to approach the data differently

You could try using a dinamic (temp) table instead of a IN clause

```
$stmt = $db_found->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT 
    callsign
  , Fname
  , ID
  , grid
  , tactical
  , latitude
  , longitude
  , email
  , Lname
FROM NetLog 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT max(recordID) as recordID
    FROM NetLog 
    WHERE callsign LIKE  ?
    AND callsign NOT IN ('W0KCN','WA0QFJ','T0EST','K0ERC','NR0AD')
    GROUP BY callsign
  ) t1 on t1.recordID = NetLog.recordID;");
```

Comment: I like the sound of this but I'm having a problem getting the syntax to work. I don't get an error exactly but I can see in my editor that the syntax won't verify. Should I enclose it in quotes (") and end with a );  ??

Comment: @KeithDKaiser   . obviusly this must be enclose in double quote (and ended by a ;    answer  updated ..

Comment: I still get errors like this: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.recordID' in 'on clause'

Comment: @KeithDKaiser   . answer  updated  ( missing alias in join  subquery)

Comment: #scaisEdge I can't thank you enough for helping me with this. Your last (very obvious but missed by me) answer did it and things are working great.

Answer (score 0):

Limit your query to 1 and sort the result by `ORDER BY recordID DESC LIMIT 1`. This way it won't have to return the entire table content.

Comment: `LIMIT` does not prevent table scan. You can `LIMIT 1` and MySQL will still scan the entire table. Read up on how `LIMIT` works.

Comment: Yes you are right N.B. but it will optimize the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize a query it's always nice to [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) it's plan to deterimine what is the problem. What I guess, is lack of index on callsign field.
You use LIKE operator, so probably [full text index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) is what you want to use.
`DISTINCT` looks as not necessary in this query as you already have `GROUP BY` in subquery